# Is iterating through a set faster than through a list?

Tags: python

I'm doing the longest consecutive sequence problem on LeetCode (https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/) and wrote the following solution:
(I made a typo earlier and put s instead of nums on line 6)

```
class Solution:
    def longestConsecutive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        s = set(nums)
        res = 0
        
        for n in nums:
            if n - 1 not in nums:
                c = 1

                while n + 1 in s:
                    c += 1
                    n += 1

                res = max(res, c)
        
        return res
```

This solution takes 4902 ms according to the website, but when I change the first for loop to

```
for n in s:
```

The runtime drops to 491 ms. Is looping through the hashset 10 times faster?

Comment: Will you show the two complete versions? Changing `for n in s:` to `for i in s:` will not make the loop faster since these are the same thing.

Comment: Also note that the "in" in `for n in s` is not the same as the "in" in `if n - 1 not in nums` or `while n+1 in s`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should've looked over what I typed up but I made a typo. The code and question should make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed `if n - 1 not in nums` to `if n - 1 not in s`, then you might see it reduces the runtime a lot. `in` operator in set is faster in list. Generally, `in` in set takes O(1), while it takes O(n) for `in` in list. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Regarding iterating in set and list, iterating through a set can be faster if there are lots of duplicates in the list. E.g., iterating through a list with `n` same elements takes O(n), while it takes O(1) since there will be only one element in the set.

Comment: The `in` operator is not what this is about, so your first part is irrelevant.

Comment: @KellyBundy It's not clear from the OP's question that what changes they made exactly. I believe that they have changed `if n - 1 not in nums:` to `if n - 1 not in s`. That's why I am mentioning the difference of `in` operator between set and list.

Comment: It would be good to state that assumption in the answer. It would've been even better to simply wait with answering until they've told us the truth.

Comment: See the question's updates. Now it's really clear that your first half is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

> Is iterating through a set faster than through a list?

No, iterating through either of these data structures is the same for the same number of elements.

However, `while n + 1 in s` does *not* necessarily iterate through the elements of `s`. `in` here is an operator that checks if the value `n+1` is an element of `s`. If `s` is a set, this operation is guaranteed to have O(1) time. If `s` is a list, then the operator will have `O(n)` time.

Comment: See the question's updates. This isn't about membership tests (your big paragraph) but really about iteration, and given the big time difference their change makes, the list and the set rather clearly don't have the same number of elements.

Comment: Also, even with the exact same objects in the exact same order, they're not equally fast. Lists get iterated significantly [faster](https://tio.run/##XY47CsMwEER7nWJLCVTYuAkGnyXIkZxs0C@rdWFCzq7YMmmy5Zs3zOaNHykOl0y1LpQCMAaHDBhyIgZy2RkWLbkl792NMcXyi617rU6IAhO80/zcU6lgSQRXwAhk4t3JvmunPsLsmsfCsigh/qxBjQJa1R6waDAHAOC9FDDK8xPpTZitGc9laTV0SkNcw@xo6pVqlUwYWbIG3vLuNHoyVesX) then, as one should expect (since iterating sets is more complicated and "wasteful").

Comment: @KellyBundy The version of the question at the time I posted this answer had `for i in s` in the code and stated that they changed it to `for n in s` which is not fundamentally different. So I made the guess that the maybe something about the `in` operator was the issue.

Comment: Well, they're fundamentally different in that one causes a name error (due to n being undefined).

Comment: Btw in general, sets might iterate arbitrarily much more slowly than lists with the same elements. [Demo](https://tio.run/##XY7LasMwFET3@orZhFwVE@IGSgjkW4ocXzcqekW6poTSb3dli246y5lzYNJT7jGczikvy5Sjh1jPVmB9ilmQObERtS236BzfxMZQ/uaRHzMrVXDFdxw@60oaU8x4hw3IJnww9ccW/aO@7tYxykWhphxSTKSVqbKzRahopf65J72yazmuZelgmixV8jZQ@0fO@GE0l/aHxg5H3SHMfuB87bXelJRtENrvzofXCXPBHjuQ4AU9v1VanqmaG9tIvSy/) where the set is over 100000 times slower.

Comment: @KellyBundy How does `for n in s` cause a name error while `for i in s` does not? Both define the name which is assigned the element during each iteration. Or do you mean there will be a name error later in the loop when you try to reference `n`? I assume that the change of the name in the loop would accompany changing all references as well.

Comment: The other way around. `for i ...` causes the name error, as it defines `i`, not `n`.

Comment: @KellyBundy umm...and likewise `for n...` defines `n`. Where's the name error?

Comment: Yeah but the later code uses `n` (not `i`), so that's what matters.

Comment: @KellyBundy Gotchya. I would assume that the later code would also be changed since the OP isn't asking about a name error. But regardless, that isn't the issue here. The original code was supposed to be `for n in nums`. And since `nums` is a list, there is a fundamental difference between that and `for n in s` where `s` is a set.

Comment: But then they wouldn't have gotten that huge time difference. Not even on LeetCode. I'll stick with what I said under the other answer, it was clear the OP didn't correctly tell us what they had done (although I suspected exactly what they've told us now) and it would've been best to simply not answer until they did.

Comment: @KellyBundy Exactly. Changing the name of a variable won't fundamentally change the algorithm.

Comment: Given that it's a local variable and thus (as far as execution is concerned) not even a name but a number (I think even the same number), I think execution is even exactly identical.